# Heap size (RAM consumtion) does not decrease after executing a save query (Spring boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, out-of-memory, ram

I remarked that after inserting 400 000 rows into mysql using spring boot, the heap size and RAM consumption go up, but never drops down after.

If a similar request is done the second time, then the heap rises with additional 5-10%.

[image]

In what the problem could be in ?
Why the heap is not cleared after executing a save query ?
Is there a problem with garbage collector ? if yes, how is it possible to fix ?

P.S: I tried some solutions provided in this article, but they did not help
https://medium.com/quick-code/what-a-recurring-outofmemory-error-taught-me-11f2061063a1

**Edited:**
I tried to select 1.2 mil records in order to fulfill the heap.
And after 20-25 minutes passed, the heap started to decrease. Why is this happening ? Isn't garbage collector suppose to clear the heap faster ? In this way, if during these 25 minutes other requests are done, server will just crash.

[image]

**Edited 2:**
Seems that when trying the same on ec2, garbage collector does not work at all. It happened already 3 times that server just runs out of memory and crashes.
Anyone know the cause ?
I ran 1 @Async thread which had inside it another 2 @Async threads called from different beans. They finished execution and after that heap never got down.
I do not have any @Cacheable methods or similar stuffs. I am just getting some data from tables, process them and update it. Have no inputstreams etc.

[image]

Comment: Garbage collection only runs when the JVM determines that it needs to.  You have 4GB of heap defined with only 1GB being used; it's likely that the JVM hasn't decided it's necessary.  Garbage collection is non-deterministic, so you can call System.gc() if you want to try to make it happen, with no guarantee that it will.  Unless you're running out of memory, I wouldn't mess with this :)

Comment: @lane.maxwell, I just did another test. Ran a select of 1.2 mil records, and the heap got fulfilled. But seems that it started to decrease only after 25 minutes passed. Why does it take so long to clear the heap ? If during this time some other requests are made, server will just crash. Do you recommend to call the System.gc() after any methods which consumes a lot of memory ? Are there any down effects of using System.gc() ?

Comment: Nah, that won't make it crash.  The JVM will GC when it needs to; the only thing that will make it crash is when you run out of heap.  You will only run out of heap when it's full and doesn't contain objects that have been marked for GC.  You can mess around with the garbage collectors in Java, but unless you have a deep understanding of what's going on there, I recommend that you don't.  Your question is theoretical, but just for giggles, see if you can force an out-of-heap error.

Comment: @lane.maxwell seems that server is crashing. Added more details in "Edited 2" section

Comment: how much RAM does your ec2 instance have? Most likely your heap is just smaller and therefore your application crashes.